# Где можно скачать документацию jquery или как скачать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular

Нужно скачать документацию JQ, чтобы можно было читать без подключения к интернету. На сайте https://jquery-docs.ru можно только сохранять. Еще нужно скачать node.js , angular.

Comment: Как вариант: с github скачивайте документацию, например: [vuejs](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org) можно скомпилировать и запустить. Либо читать файлы `*.md` расширением для хрома [`Markdown Reader`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-reader/gpoigdifkoadgajcincpilkjmejcaanc)

Answer (score 1):

https://devdocs.io прекрасный сайт с кучей документаций:

- https://devdocs.io/jquery/ - jQuery
- https://devdocs.io/angular/ - Angular
- https://devdocs.io/node~10_lts/ - Node

P.S. Это первая выдача по запросу `jquery download documentation`

Comment: Уберите - сразу возле этой ссылке https://devdocs.io-